# Preprocessing a list of list removing stopwords for doc2vec using map without losing words order

Tags: python, list, gensim, stop-words

I am implementing a simple `doc2vec` with `gensim`, **not** a `word2vec`

I need to remove stopwords without losing the correct order to a list of list.

Each list is a document and, as I understood for doc2vec, the model will have as input a list of TaggedDocuments

`model = Doc2Vec(lst_tag_documents, vector_size=5, window=2, min_count=1, workers=4)`

```
dataset = [['We should remove the stopwords from this example'],
     ['Otherwise the algo'],
     ["will not work correctly"],
     ['dont forget Gensim doc2vec takes list_of_list' ]]

STOPWORDS = ['we','i','will','the','this','from']


def word_filter(lst):
  lower=[word.lower() for word in lst]
  lst_ftred = [word for word in lower if not word in STOPWORDS]
  return lst_ftred

lst_lst_filtered= list(map(word_filter,dataset))
print(lst_lst_filtered)
```

Output:

```
[['we should remove the stopwords from this example'], ['otherwise the algo'], ['will not work correctly'], ['dont forget gensim doc2vec takes list_of_list']]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[' should remove the stopwords   example'], ['otherwise the algo'], [' not work correctly'], ['dont forget gensim doc2vec takes list_of_list']]
```

---

- **What was my mistake and how to fix?**
- **There are other efficient ways to solve this issue without losing the
  proper order?**

---

List of questions I examined before asking:

[How to apply a function to each sublist of a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060970/how-to-apply-a-function-to-each-sublist-of-a-list-in-python)

- I studied this and tried to apply on my specific case

[Removing stopwords from list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413876/removing-stopwords-from-list-of-lists)

- The order is important I can't use set

[Removing stopwords from a list of text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042163/removing-stopwords-from-a-list-of-text-files)

- This could be a possible solution is similar to what I have implemented.
- I undestood that the difference, but I don't know how to deal with it.
  In my case the document is not tokenized (and should not be tokenized because is a doc2vec not a word2vec)

[How to remove stop words using nltk or python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486337/how-to-remove-stop-words-using-nltk-or-python)

- In this question the SO is dealing with a list not a list of list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lower` is a list of one element, `word not in STOPWORDS` will return `False`. Take the first item in the list with index and split by blank space

```
lst_ftred = ' '.join([word for word in lower[0].split() if word not in STOPWORDS])
# output: ['should remove stopwords example', 'otherwise algo', 'not work correctly', 'dont forget gensim doc2vec takes list_of_list']
# 'the' is also in STOPWORDS
```

Answer (score 1):

First, note it's not that important to remove stopwords from `Doc2Vec` training. Second, note that such tiny toy datasets won't deliver interesting results from `Doc2Vec`. Tha algorithm, like `Word2Vec`, only starts to show its value when trained on large datasets with (1) many, many more unique words than the number of vector dimensions; and (2) lots of varied examples of the usage of each word - at least a few, ideally dozens or hundreds.

Still, if you wanted to strip stopwords, it'd be easiest if you did it *after* tokenizing the raw strings. (That is, splitting the strings into lists-of-words. That's the format `Doc2Vec` will need anyway.) And, you *don't* want your `dataset` to be a list-of-lists-with-one-string-each. Instead, you want it to be either a list-of-strings (at first), then a list-of-lists-with-many-tokens-each.

The following should work:

```py
string_dataset = [
     'We should remove the stopwords from this example',
     'Otherwise the algo',
     "will not work correctly",
     'dont forget Gensim doc2vec takes list_of_list',
]

STOPWORDS = ['we','i','will','the','this','from']

# Python list comprehension to break into tokens
tokenized_dataset = [s.split() for s in string_dataset]

def filter_words(tokens):
    """lowercase each token, and keep only if not in STOPWORDS"""
    return [token.lower() for token in tokens if token not in STOPWORDS]

filtered_dataset = [filter_words(s) for sent in tokenized_dataset]
```

Finally, because as noted above, `Doc2Vec` needs multiple word examples to work well, it's almost always a bad idea to use `min_count=1`.

Comment: Tnx, yes I tried to create a Minimum Reproducible Example, but the dataset it's definitely bigger than +100k documents. What was not clear to me from the documentation, it that also in doc2vec you have to tokenize all the strings that constitute the document.

Comment: The docs for the `TaggedDocument` class (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument) – which is the recommended type for `Doc2Vec` training examples) – describe its first argument, `words`, as 'a list of unicode string tokens`, and intro examples show preprocessing strings into lists-of-tokens, as in <https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html>. Was there some part of the docs or examples that indicated to you otherwise?

Comment: I am sure I wrongly interpreted an unofficial tutorial that I can't find anymore(that's why I think I made a mistake), because before asking this question I was wandering why I  was working with list of list. 
BTW I will study again (and better) all the official tutorials